# how to prefill rails form_for with fields from another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` Model and an `Order` Model.

When user confirm his order, he needs to fill out personal information for this particular order (and I like to keep this info in the order instead of referencing the user for it, in case the user would like to order for someone else)

So I have a `form_for @order`, which has the exact same fields as the `User`, and I'd like to have it populated with the User info.

I figure I can do this:

```
      <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, value: current_user.first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'%>
```

and then do `value: current_user.last_name`, etc. etc. etc. Just seemed really dirty and wonder what better ways there might be. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign value when initialize new object for @order like following, maybe in your controller

```
@order = Order.new(first_name: current_user.first_name)
```